# Wanted but not invoked, Kotlin, RxJava, MVP, Mockito

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, mockito, rx-java

I am trying to write a simple test for my `MainPresenter(SchedulerProvider)` class. It should check if the `showEventFragment(String)` and `showPromptFragment(String)` shows up after successful API response.

I create `MainPresenter` instance in `MainActivity` like this:

```
private val presenter: MainContract.Presenter = MainPresenter(AppSchedulerProvider())
```

Presenter class:

```
class MainPresenter(private val scheduler: SchedulerProvider) : MainContract.Presenter{

    private val subscriptions = CompositeDisposable()
    private val api: RxApiServiceInterface = RxApiServiceInterface.create()
    private lateinit var view: MainContract.View

    override fun subscribe() {

    }

    override fun unsubscribe() {
        subscriptions.clear()
    }


    override fun loadProfileData() {
        view.showLoadingView()
        val subscribe = api.getProfileDataRequest()
            .subscribeOn(scheduler.io())
            .observeOn(scheduler.ui())
            .subscribe({profileList : List<Profile> ->
                view.showEventFragment(profileList[0].profile_id)
                view.showPromptFragment(profileList[0].profile_id)
            },{ error ->
                view.showErrorMessage(error.message.toString())
                view.showRetryView()
            })

        subscriptions.add(subscribe)
    }

    override fun attach(view: MainContract.View) {
        this.view = view
    }

}
```

Test class:

```
class MainPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var view: MainContract.View

    private var api: RxApiServiceInterface = RxApiServiceInterface.create()
    private lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter
    private lateinit var testScheduler: TestScheduler
    private lateinit var testSchedulerProvider: TestSchedulerProvider

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)


        testScheduler = TestScheduler()
        testSchedulerProvider = TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler)

        mainPresenter = MainPresenter(testSchedulerProvider)
        mainPresenter.attach(view)
    }


    @Test
    fun getProfileSuccess() {

        val address = Address("SillyStreet", "4", "80333", "NY")
        val contact = Contact("i.am@dummy.com", "000 000 000 00")
        val mockedProfile = Profile(
            "freemium_profile",
            "Dum",
            "my",
            "male",
            "Sil ly",
            true,
            "First Class",
            "1989-01-01",
            address,
            contact,
            listOf("freemium", "signup_complete")
        )

        doReturn(Single.just(listOf(mockedProfile)))
            .`when`(api)
            .getProfileDataRequest()


        mainPresenter.loadProfileData()

        testSchedulerProvider.testScheduler.triggerActions()

        verify(view).showLoadingView()
        verify(view).showEventFragment(mockedProfile.profile_id)
        verify(view).showPromptFragment(mockedProfile.profile_id)
    }

}
```

RxApiServiceInterface interface:

```
interface RxApiServiceInterface {

    @GET("user/customer/profiles")
    fun getProfileDataRequest() : Single<List<Profile>>

    companion object {
        private val restClient by lazy {
            RestClient.createRetrofit(API_URL)
        }

        fun create(): RxApiServiceInterface = restClient.create(RxApiServiceInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

TestSchedulerProvider class:

```
class TestSchedulerProvider constructor(val testScheduler: TestScheduler) : SchedulerProvider {
    override fun ui(): Scheduler = testScheduler
    override fun computation(): Scheduler = testScheduler
    override fun io(): Scheduler = testScheduler
}
```

I am using these test libs:

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.22.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.22.0'
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.2.71'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'
```

What the hell am I doing wrong, that I still get the "Wanted but not invoked error"?
The logs also says:

```
However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
view.showLoadingView();
```

but I am not suprised about that as this method is outside API query.

Comment: Have the `api.getProfileDataRequest()` have some side-effect by using `Single.fromCallable(() -> { println("Source"); return listOf(...); })`. Or you could try `advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` instead of `triggerActions()`.

Comment: Hi, you found some solution for this problem?? I'm getting the same error whit, more or less, same implementation

Comment: @S.P. Hi mate. Nah I haven't found solution. Generally I would suggest you to use MVVM architecture with RxJava.